# How to customize CXF proxy to add @QueryParam to each method?

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I have an CXF proxy interface, e.g.

```
@Path("/resources")
public interface ResourceService {
    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces("application/json")
    List<Resource> list(@QueryParam("name") String name);

    ...
}
```

And a call:

```
ResourceService service = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://localhost:8080/app/rest"
service.list("name");
```

Is it possible to customize the proxy so it will add another QueryParam to each method invocation? So `list()` would became:

```
    List<Resource> list(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("ticket") String ticket);
```

Basically I need to supply SSO ticket to all the methods but don't want to specify it everywhere in the code but rather to create some kind of extension that will pass it transparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the answer myself:

```
WebClient.client(service).query("ticket", ticket);
```